# Найти два массива с одинаковым идентификатором и взять из него вложенный массив

Tags: javascript

Есть переменная, в которую записаны два json-массива. Первый:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "bar": "foo",
  "array": [
    {
      "price": 1111
    }
  ],
  "sign": "1a2b3c"
}
```

Второй:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "bar": "foo",
  "array": [
    {
      "price": 1222
    }
  ],
  "sign": "1a2b3c"
}
```

Как вы могли заметить, у них идентичны `sign`. Это нужно для того, чтобы можно было идентифицировать идентичные друг другу массивы(за исключением значения `price`). Что мне нужно сделать - нужно выбрать такие массивы, в которых общий `sign`(т.е. `arr[0].sign == arr[1].sign`), взять из них массив `array[0]`, и засунуть в первый массив, удалить полностью массив, из которого был взят `array[0]`. Результатом работы скрипта должен получиться массив:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "bar": "foo",
  "array": [
    {
      "price": 1111
    },
    {
      "price": 1222
    }
  ],
  "sign": "1a2b3c"
}
```

Вложенные массивы в `array[]` должны быть отсортированы между собой по значению `price`.

Comment: вопрос то в чём? ты сам всё описал. делай то, что описал словами

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да нормальный вопрос ведь, очевидно, что если он возник, то непонятно как это сделать...

Comment: @diraria вопроса я тут не вижу. да и описал он логику уже всю. как можно не знать как сделать если уже сам описал как сделать? А судя по тому, что у ТС 252 вопроса, то те самые базовые знания для выполнения такой простой операции явно у автора есть.. поэтому мне не понятно в чем проблемы возникли.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я не знаю, как мне делать выборку таких sign. Нужно сверить каждый элемент массива друг с другом. А как? Просто `for()` не подойдёт же, наверное.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin отчего же не подойдет если нужно сверить каждый элемент массива друг с другом?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский потому, что с `for()` нужно будет брать 0 элемент и сверять его со всеми, потом брать 1 элемент и сверять его со всеми и так далее(моё виденье). А вот человек снизу сделал при помощи `.reduce()`. И сделано довольно элегантно и компактно. Буду изучать код и разбираться в алгоритме. Просто потому, что мне легче по коду изучать программирование. Чтобы был наглядный пример.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin  reduce - это цикл, для справки. с помощью for получилось бы тоже самое

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin однако если есть хоть какие-то мысли - стоит их описывать. иначе это всё смахивает на "вот задача - напишите мне код"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вариант

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "foo": "bar",
    "bar": "foo",
    "array": [
      {
        "price": 1222
      }
    ],
    "sign": "1a2b3c"
  },
  {
    "foo": "bar",
    "bar": "foo",
    "array": [
      {
        "price": 2222
      }
    ],
    "sign": "1a2b3b"
  },
  {
    "foo": "bar",
    "bar": "foo",
    "array": [
      {
        "price": 3222
      }
    ],
    "sign": "1a2b3c"
  },
  {
    "foo": "bar",
    "bar": "foo",
    "array": [
      {
        "price": 4222
      }
    ],
    "sign": "1a2b3b"
  }
];
  
  const res = arr.reduce((r,v)=>{
    if(!(r.hasOwnProperty(v.sign))){
      r[v.sign] = v;
    }else{    
      r[v.sign].array.push(v.array[0]);
    }
    
    return r;
  }, {});
  
  let ar =[];
  for(let o in res){
    ar.push(res[o]);
  }
  
  console.log(ar);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Почитал код, разобрался, что и как работает. Теперь знаю, что `reduce()` перебирает каждый элемент массива с сохранением значений каждого предыдущего :) Подскажите ещё, а можно ли таким же образом сравнивать массивы не в пределах одной переменной, а в пределах двух? Например, сравнить sign'ы из одного массива с sign'ами другого?

Comment: reduce пробегает по конкретному массиву, поэтому нет наверное.

Comment: @tillin а если сделать так: запустить цикл на втором массиве и сверять sign текущего элемента с sign первого массива и если sign идентичны, то пушить `array` второго массива в первый?

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin можно конечно